# Dynamically update dataframe where conditions are provide through another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an input dataframe like below:

```
**ID  |  NAME  |  AGE  |  SALARY  |  TYPE**  
1  |  AB  |  26  |  33000  |  ABC  
2  |  CD  |  29  |  41000  |  DEF  
3  |  DE  |  26  |  53000  |  BCD
```

I have another dataframe where condition to update the input dataframe are listed:

```
**Column_to_be_updated  |  Value_to_be_update  |  COLUMN  |  OPERATOR  |  VALUE**  
TYPE  |  FFF  |  SALARY  |  >=  | 40000  
TYPE  |  GGG  |  AGE  |  <=  | 27
```

I want to apply the above condition on input dataframe and my expected output is:

```
**ID  |  NAME  |  AGE  |  SALARY  |  TYPE**  
1  |  AB  |  26  |  33000  |  GGG  
2  |  CD  |  29  |  41000  |  FFF  
3  |  DE  |  26  |  53000  |  GGG
```

Any way to do this efficiently in Python?

Also, I am not able to provide logical operator like AND/OR in the expression dataframe, If you have any idea/logic to include that as well in the expression dataframe and then update input data based on that, that will solve all of my problem. Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take using `df.eval` and `np.where`

```
cond = df1.eval(df2[['COLUMN','OPERATOR','VALUE']].astype(str).agg(' '.join,1)).T
vals = np.where(cond,df2['Value_to_be_update'],np.nan)

m = pd.DataFrame(vals,columns=df2['Column_to_be_updated'].to_numpy())
df1.loc[:,df2['Column_to_be_updated'].unique()] = m.groupby(m.columns,axis=1).last()
```

---

```
print(df1)

   ID NAME  AGE  SALARY TYPE
0   1   AB   26   33000  GGG
1   2   CD   29   41000  FFF
2   3   DE   26   53000  GGG
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
def execute_upd(base, chngs):
    for i,r in chngs.iterrows():
        base.loc[eval(f"base['{r['COLUMN']}']{r['OPERATOR']}{r['VALUE']}"), r['Column_to_be_updated']]=r['Value_to_be_update']
    return base
```

Now assuming `df1` is your base df, and `df2` is the one with updates:

```py
df1=execute_upd(df1,df2)
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> df1

   ID NAME  AGE  SALARY TYPE
0   1   AB   26   33000  GGG
1   2   CD   29   41000  FFF
2   3   DE   26   53000  GGG
```